# Make a TextArea fill up the rest of the page vertically?

Tags: html, css

Is there an easy way to make the height of a  fill up to the height of the page?

Comment: [notepad.cc](http://notepad.cc/) demonstrates this effect – you can try to figure out how they do it. Their method resizes the textarea live when the window is resized and works even while JavaScript is disabled. I’m not sure if it relies on knowing the height of the content above and below the textarea.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is important to understand that setting `height: 100%` for a textarea will only work in IE if you explicitly set it to quirks mode, though it works as expected in Firefox. The W3C states that the size of a textarea is defined in rows rather than pixels, etc.

Shown below is an easy way to ensure that the size of the textarea *always* takes up the entire body height, taking into account the godzillions of user-installed toolbars, etc., varying monitor resolutions and possibly even resized windows. The key is the simple JS method and its placement. The form is just there to simulate normal textboxes and labels.

```
<html>
    <head runat="server"><title>Look, Mom! No Scrollbars!</title></head>
    <body onload="resizeTextArea()" onresize="resizeTextArea()"> 
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div id="formWrapper" style="height:200px">
                <input type="text" value="test" />
                <input type="text" value="test" />
            </div>
            <textarea id="area" style="width: 100%"></textarea>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function resizeTextArea() {
                //Wrap your form contents in a div and get its offset height
                var heightOfForm = document.getElementById('formWrapper').offsetHeight;
                //Get height of body (accounting for user-installed toolbars)
                var heightOfBody = document.body.clientHeight;
                var buffer = 35; //Accounts for misc. padding, etc.
                //Set the height of the textarea dynamically
                document.getElementById('area').style.height =
                  (heightOfBody - heightOfForm) - buffer;
                //NOTE: For extra panache, add onresize="resizeTextArea()" to the body
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Copy and paste it into a new page. It works in both FF and IE.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Here’s [the W3C spec for the `textarea` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-textarea-element.html#the-textarea-element). I don’t see where it says that the size of a textarea is defined in rows *rather than* pixels, so I don’t understand what you mean by that. Yes, it starts off as tall as some number of rows, thanks to the `rows` attribute, but after that, you are able to give it whatever height you want, for instance, with the CSS `#area { height: 100px; }`.

Comment: [JS Bin of this answer](http://jsbin.com/ugosup/1/edit). In both Firefox and Chrome, it works for me in the [code view](http://jsbin.com/ugosup/1/edit) but fails in the [full-page view](http://jsbin.com/ugosup/1).